create cmake variable during add_custom_target call
I have a CI pipeline which generates an .exe alongside the needed dll. I'm trying to package the whole thing into a tar.gz for the sake of practicality.
so I tried to declare to following cmake code :
file(
    GLOB 
DLL_FILES 
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/*.exe
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/*.dll)

add_custom_target(
    generate_tar
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
    COMMAND tar czf "output.tar.gz" ${DLL_FILES})

Thus, at the end of my pipeline, I'm calling generate_tar which fails with the following message : tar: no files or directories specified, which is explainable because file command is ran when this CMake file is included, at the begining, when my project has not been generated yet.
So I'd like to create this DDL_FILES variable when calling add_custom_target but I can't find tips on how to do this properply (i'm fairly to CMake use).

You cannot define CMake variable when add_custom_target is called: at that time no CMake environment exists at all. You may glob files in your COMMAND, by using shell-specific syntax. Or you may write a separate CMake script and call it in your COMMAND via cmake -P. Note, that has a dedicated mechanism for project packaging: CPack. Its usage is covered e.g. in CMake tutorial.


I'd like to create this DDL_FILES variable when calling add_custom_target

You can't - the files are not there. You have to get the files after build. You could execute shell which will execute globbing or find the files or write a cmake script that will run from add_custom_target or similar.
add_custom_target(
    generate_tar
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
    COMMAND sh -c 'tar czf "output.tar.gz"  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/*.exe ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/*.dll'
)

But why would you generate output.tar.gz if input did not change? The proper solution it to enumerate all dependencies, all targets you are depending on,  and create output.tar.gz from these targets.
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"/output.tar.gz
    DEPENDS some_target some_library
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMAND tar czf "output.tar.gz"
         $<TARGET_FILE:some_target>
         $<TARGET_FILE:some_library>
    VERBATIM
)
add_custom_target(generate_tar DEPENDS "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"/output.tar.gz)

